# How to store user Input temporarily in an arraylist and then store them permanently in a file (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, file, arraylist, input

I have a class named (Person) it takes all the user information and do some calculations.
Anyway my problem is that I want to store the user information in an ArrayList temporarily and
then permanently in a File. but I couldn't actually store them

```
ArrayList<Person> info = new ArrayList<>();
    System.out.println("What is Your Name ? ");
    person.setName(input.nextLine());
    System.out.println("Please Enter Your Age: ");
    person.age = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please Enter Your Weight: ");
    person.weight = input.nextInt();
```

So as you can see, age and weight are public fields in (Person) class and Name is a private that's
why I used setName method. So how can I store these 3 information only into ArrayList and then into File ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an instance of `Person`
2. Populate the fields of `person`
3. Add `person` to list.

```java
final int ENOUGH = 10;
ArrayList<Person> info = new ArrayList<>();

while (true) {
    Person person = new Person();
    System.out.println("What is Your Name ? ");
    person.setName(input.nextLine());
    System.out.println("Please Enter Your Age: ");
    person.age = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please Enter Your Weight: ");
    person.weight = input.nextInt();

    info.add(person);

    System.out.println("Type 0 to continue");
    boolean userWantsOut = input.nextInt() != 0;
    // check user input OR size of the list for exit condition and break
    if (userWantsOut || info.size() == ENOUGH) {
        break;
    }
}
```

As for saving the list into file, the question is far too broad and needs to be specified at least which type of file should be written: text (plain text, CSV, JSON etc.) or binary (using ObjectOutputStream, JSONB, etc.)

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! that was really helpful. and for the file it should be written as plain text. and thanks again a lot